# Extract the vowels element from an array of string data type of dimension 3

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, string, numpy-ndarray

i am Trying to extract vowels element of each string value and a separate 3,3 array consisting of vowels of respective string value.

INPUT= array ([['teeth', 'cheek', 'chin'],

```
   ['eye', 'ear', 'nose'],

   ['hair', 'leg', 'hand']]
```

Expected Output= array ([['ee','ee','i'],

```
                   ['ee','ea','oe'],

                   ['ai','e','a']]
```

i tried many ways but no result ,PLease help me to get the solution,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
INPUT=[['teeth', 'cheek', 'chin'],['eye', 'ear', 'nose'], ['hair', 'leg', 'hand']]
out=[]
for list_i in INPUT:
    temp_list =[]
    for word in list_i:
        sel = [w for w in word if w in vowels]
        temp_list.append(''.join(sel))
    out.append(temp_list)

print(out)
```

Output: `[['ee', 'ee', 'i'], ['ee', 'ea', 'oe'], ['ai', 'e', 'a']]`

Code explanation:

```
[w for w in word if w in vowels]
```

In this line , the for loop is used to iterate over each letter of a single word (`word`). If the letter (`w`) is a vowel, then it is insert in the list (`sel`).

```
temp_list.append(''.join(sel))
```

This line is just a parsing: the list of letters `sel` is converted to a string and inserted in `temp_list`. I hope it is more clear now!

Comment: sel = [w for w in word if w in vowels]    - this code line ,i couldn't understand it ,please elaborate it in simple words  since i am a beginner                                                                         also -temp_list.append(''.join(sel))